# Firebase.auth().onstateChanged() not working after clearing browser cache

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

I cleared my browser cache and now my app cant login

```
export function IsUserRedirect({ user, loggedInPath, children, ...rest}){
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={() => {
                if(!user){
                    return children;
                }
                if(user){
                    return (
                        <Redirect
                            to={{
                                pathname: loggedInPath
                            }}
                            />
                    )
                }
                return null;
            }}
            />
    )
}

export function ProtectedRoute({ user, children, ...rest}){
    return(
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={({location}) => {
                if(user){
                    return children;
                }
                if(!user){
                    return (
                        <Redirect
                            to={{
                                pathname: 'signin',
                                state: { from : location}
                            }}
                        />
                      )
                }
                return null;
            }}
            />
    )
}
```

I think it stored my login info on the browser as a localstorage but after clearing it still recognizes it as the user is logged in and takes me to the next page.
But on the next page i have kept a loading state for getting user data, as it doesnt has any user it just keeps loading and goes nowhere. can someone help

```
export default function useAuthListener(){
    const [user, setUser] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authUser')));
    const {firebase} = useContext(FirebaseContext);

    useEffect(() => {
       
        const listener = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((authUser) => {
            
          if(authUser){
                localStorage.setItem('authUser', JSON.stringify(authUser));
                setUser(authUser);
            }else {
                localStorage.removeItem('authUser');
                setUser(null);
            }
        });
        return ()=> listener();
    }, []);

    return { user};
}
```

Comment: This seems like a code-smell `return { user};`. By the time this code runs, the user state won't have been updated yet.

Answer (score 0):

just a quick suggestion:

```
localStorage.clear();
```

[Source:](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_storage_clear.asp)

(Another aproach might be a reboot, to see if it acts differently...)

Greetings,
Alexander

Comment: Hey, I already tried that method but it did not work for me. As  my localstorage was cleared out and my authuser was showing null in the console. But somehow IsuserRedirect() part of my code was not redirecting on my children component even though the user is null. Instead it was going for the else clause and rendering the loggedinPath page